# Anonymous read-only access to Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement anonymous read-only access to files stored in Google Drive via the Drive JS API. The Google Drive belongs to a Service Account and all files are configured to permit public read-only access. Anyone with the URL can currently access the Drive UI (in a web browser) and view these files without authentication.

My goal is to show information about these files on a separate web page using data retrieved via JS API, however it appears that Google only supports access to the API if the API client (the web page) is authenticated or the end user (the viewer of a web page) is authenticated via OAuth. Given that the files are already public it seems like it should be possible to provide anonymous read-only access via the API.

There are examples of an API client authenticating using a credentials JSON file containing credentials for a Service Account, instead of requiring the end user to authenticate via OAuth, but this requires the client to submit a JSON file when authenticating. As this is a web page I would need to embed the credentials JSON (including Private Key) in my public-visible source and this is not a good idea.

One option is to write my own API that authenticates (server-side) with Google Drive using a credentials JSON file and essentially proxies anonymous requests from my web page to the Google Drive API, but that seems like too much work for something that I believe should be simple.

Is there any way to provide anonymous read-only access to public Google Drive files via the JS API?

Comment: Sorry I got confused with the details. Earlier you mentioned that the Drive belongs to a Service account and all files were already in public read-only access. Then you mentioned your goal is to show the information of these files (You plan to use Drive API to get the file information in the service account Drive). But in your last statement, you are asking how to provide a read-only access for drive files using API? Can you clarify what do you really want to do?

Comment: @RonM I've updated the question, but just in case it's still not clear: I want a web page on an existing site to fetch information about the public files currently in Google Drive via the API, so that they can be listed outside of the Google Drive web UI. Right now any user can anonymously visit the Google Drive web UI and view these files, but it does not seem possible to access data or metadata about the same files anonymously via the Google Drive API